# Push notification in Blackberry device

Tags: java, blackberry, push-notification

I started working with push notification and I had developed server side code + client side code and downloaded Blackberry push services SDK and i got the ID, Port NO. and the password and all the crediantials that is been provided by RIM.

Now the problem is that I am not getting the notification from the device.

Client side URL is : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857

and Server side URL is : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Push-API-sample-code-needed/m-p/471216#M109

Comment: Did you replace the sample suffixes with the BIS suffix in client code?

Comment: Hi,I dont know how to do that pls help

Comment: In the `PushAgent.java` class, edit the `CONNECTION_SUFFIX` constant with the BIS suffix (which RIM should have provided you, because they used to keep it secret despite everybody knows it).

Comment: That i came to know but from where i will get that BIS Suffix(Where it is hidden and from where should i get it)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change also `CONNECTION_SUFFIX` constant. You should replace "seekrit string" with valid BIS-B suffix. You should or could get it from RIM.

Comment: How to get that BIS-B suffix from RIM

Comment: That's exactly what I said above.

Comment: And why did you minus my answer?

Comment: Sorry but I havn't minus your answer ... My reputation is not enough to rate any answer.

Comment: That was comment to @Mister Smith

Comment: Hi, Eugen Martynov I am still facing the problem please help me .

Comment: What issue exactly do you have?